# Как регистры процессора сохраняют свои значения между задачами?

Tags: ассемблер, cpu

я только начала разбираться в ассемблере и устройстве процессора, и у меня появился такой вопрос. На данный момент все операционные системы многозадачные, что значит что одновременно могут выполняться несколько задач. Но на самом низшем уровне процессор не может выполнять задачи одновременно. Как я понимаю, он выполняет их по кругу, инструкцию от одной задачи, потом от другой, потом от третьей. Как тогда в рамках одной задачи значения регистра постоянны и не меняются при обращении другой задачи к этим же регистрам? Возможно, я что-то не так понимаю, не могли бы вы объяснить этот момент, спасибо.

Comment: *`"Как я понимаю, он выполняет их по кругу, инструкцию от одной задачи, потом от другой, потом от третьей"`* -- это не верно. Процессор выполняет инструкции *одной задачи* в течении длительного времени, пока сама задача не передаст управление ОС (сделав системный вызов) или не произойдет прерывания от периферии, которое обрабатывается в ОС (прерывания от таймера проходят периодически, скажем, каждую миллисекунду). Перед возвратом из прерывания ОС может переключить процессор на инструкции другой задачи. При получении прерывания ОС сохраняет регистры, а при возврате восстанавливает их

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регистры процессора в "неактивное" время хранятся в TSS контексте задачи. Параллельная задача может получить доступ к регистрам другой задачи обрабатывая байты просто как память.

Эти данные хранятся в том же месте где GDT LDT дескрипторы. Отдельно ТSS можно почитать. GDT - это корень таблицы, один из элементов которой может быть TSS. Хранятся структуры в оперативной памяти. Если хватает прав доступа - то можно править их прямо в памяти.

Под виндой доступ к регистрам можно получить функцией SetThreadContext GetThreadContext. Структура  CONTEXT виндовая частично повторяет структуру TSS. Что бы подменить значение регистров задачу нужно приостановить. При переключении на задачу определенное к-во тактов ЦП уходит на чтение регистров из памяти ТSS в сверхбыструю память регистров (а при приостановке задачи чтение назад). ЦП это делает сам, без вмешательств со стороны. Единственное что можно самому сделать - это сказать - срочно бери вот эту TSS выполнять, или можно стопнуть задачу. Также можно можно сказать чтобы не все регистры хранил (например не хранил mmx или sse группу регистров).

Если хотите под современные процессоры - то можно скачать мануалы на процессор на сайте http://intel.com  или на сайте AMD. Там есть описание и под x86 и под x64 режим. Если для общего ознакомления - то любое где 386 и TSS например как ниже

Ссылки

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table
- http://www.sasm.narod.ru/docs/pm/pm_tss/chap_3.htm
- http://programming-lang.com/html/cpu/386/1.html
- https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-246.html

Comment: Большое спасибо, именно то, что меня интересовало

Answer (score 0):

> Как я понимаю, он выполняет их по кругу, инструкцию от одной задачи, потом от другой, потом от третьей. Как тогда в рамках одной задачи значения регистра постоянны и не меняются при обращении другой задачи к этим же регистрам?

Здесь нужно вспомнить базовые основы..

1. Все процессы/действия в системе должны протекать синхронно, поэтому напрямую зависят от точности хода таймеров. Для часов достаточно милли/сек 0.000 и их обслуживает древний таймер **PIT/RTC** (Real-Time-Clock). Но для остальных процессов это крупная единица, и требуется более точный таймер с разрешением в микро/сек 0.000000, и нано/сек 0.000000000. С такой скважностью работает таймер **ACPI** (хотя способен и PIT), но в системе имеется и более точный современный таймер **HPET** (High-Precision-Event-Timer), который нужно включить в биосе. Включение HPET наводит порядок в системе, устраняя "траекторию пьяного гонщика".
2. В ОС может быть запущено более 1000 исполняемых потоков и чтобы имитировать многозадачность, системный планировщик чередует их исполнение, выделяя каждому свой **"квант"** времени. По умолчанию в Win один квант равен 15 нано/сек, по истечению которых управление передаётся сл.исполняемому потоку - такой алго действует всегда! Более того в ОС имеется "система приоритетов" 0-15, благодаря которой, например, системный "диспетчер задач" может выгружать зависшие потоки. Потоки с обычным приоритетом (наши) не получат управления, пока работает поток с более высоким приоритетом. Узнать приоритет своего/чужого процесса можно в диспетчере-задач, правой кнопкой мыши.
3. В системе имеется глобальная таблица GDT, в которой описывается и "сегмент состояния задачи/процесса" TSS. Каждое ядро процессора имеет свою таблицу GDT, и соответственно свой сегмент памяти TSS. Ядро CPU, на котором будет исполняться процесс, назначается системой при его старте и называется "Affinity Mask" - эта инфа хранится в структуре-паспорта процесса EPROCESS. Таким образом, когда планировщик переключает потоки, состояние их регистров сбрасывается в строго сегмент TSS того ядра, на котором работал этот поток, а не в TSS соседнего ядра - иначе невозможно будет вести учёт.